# Change Time format Powershell Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, time-format

I have a few Servers run in Microsoft Azure. I always had the timeformat dd/mm/yyyy but after this weekends update it changed for all of them to mm/dd/yyyy. For some reason im having a hard time fixing this small isue.

I need to change it because i run a application on the Server which does stuff with the time and it will also be printed out wrong. I tried to change it via the Date and time settings and this changes all when im on the server, but the application still shows the wrong format.

So I had a similar problem with the timezone, nothing i did on the Server itself did change anything i had to go via Windows Admin Center(in the Azure platform) and change it there with powershell, that did the job.

Now if if i do a `get-culture` it shows the wrong one(in windows admin center) even though its shown correct local on the server.

So now the question how can I change the time format for the entire Server permanent on every User in powershell, I dont need this other timeformat at all its not used in my Country.

Comment: Using `Set-Culture` sets it for the "current user account." Under which account does the application run? This might be a question for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @lit for pointing in the right direction. [`Set-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-culture?view=windowsserver2022-ps) is used to set the user culture for the current account. Use below PowerShell script to achieve your requirement.

```
$changeto = 'en-US'  
[CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture = $changeto
[CultureInfo]::CurrentUICulture = $changeto
Set-Culture -CultureInfo $changeto | Out-Null
[DateTime]::Now.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')
```

*Output*:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use [`az mysql server configuration set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/mysql/server/configuration?view=azure-cli-latest#az-mysql-server-configuration-set) CLI command to change the date and time format of a server permanently.